# Adding default define button to annotation toolbar. iOS PSPDFKIT

Tags: ios, objective-c, pspdfkit

I just started using PSPDFKIT and I am having trouble with the default define functionality that you get with iOS.

I want the define button to show up instead of "Wikipedia" when I select a word.

I looked into calling the define button from other toolbar, but is it allowed?